# How to solve the issue like app service will not be call on every time?

Tags: microsoft-band

I am working on Microsoft band technology, in one of my current scenario as I am sending Sms in background (means even app is not open in foreground also its working like sending Sms successfully).

For that I created the appservice by taking with Windows Runtime Component as a template.

In that app service I wrote the code for how to connect to the band and how to create the tile and how to register the Events.

And also wrote the code in Button_Pressed event for sending the Sms to others.

After that I configured the app service in package. Manifest file like this below figure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArDl5.png)

My issue is appservice will not be call on every time.it will be call on two or three times per day.

Is the problem in my code or issue of Microsoft health app?

```
using Microsoft.Band;
using Microsoft.Band.Notifications;
using Microsoft.Band.Tiles;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.AppService;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Popups;

namespace AppServiceEvents
{
public sealed class MyTileEventHandler : IBackgroundTask
{
    private BackgroundTaskDeferral backgroundTaskDeferral;
    private AppServiceConnection appServiceConnection;
    IBandClient bandClient;
    //BandTile tile;
    //IEnumerable<BandTile> tiles;
    //Guid tileGuid;
    public  void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        this.backgroundTaskDeferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral(); taskInstance.Canceled += OnTaskCanceled;
        //await ConnectBand();
        // Add handlers for tile events  
        BackgroundTileEventHandler.Instance.TileOpened += EventHandler_TileOpened;
        BackgroundTileEventHandler.Instance.TileClosed += EventHandler_TileClosed;
        BackgroundTileEventHandler.Instance.TileButtonPressed += EventHandler_TileButtonPressed;
        // Set up handler for incoming app service request messages 
        var details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as AppServiceTriggerDetails;
        this.appServiceConnection = details.AppServiceConnection;
        this.appServiceConnection.RequestReceived +=OnRequestReceived; 
    }

    private async void OnRequestReceived(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        var messageDeferral = args.GetDeferral();
        ValueSet response = new ValueSet();
        ValueSet request = args.Request.Message;
        // Decode the received message and call the appropriate handler 
        BackgroundTileEventHandler.Instance.HandleTileEvent(request);
        // Send the response 
        await args.Request.SendResponseAsync(response);  
        messageDeferral.Complete();
    }

    private void OnTaskCanceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        DisconnectBand();
        if (this.backgroundTaskDeferral != null)
        {
            this.backgroundTaskDeferral.Complete();
        }
    }
    private void EventHandler_TileOpened(object sender, BandTileEventArgs<IBandTileOpenedEvent> e)
    {
        // TODO: Handle the tile opening
        LogEvent(String.Format("EventHandler_TileOpened: TileId={0} Timestamp={1}", e.TileEvent.TileId, e.TileEvent.Timestamp));
        // We create a Band connection when the tile is opened and keep it connected until the tile closes.
        ConnectBand();
    }  
    private void EventHandler_TileClosed(object sender, BandTileEventArgs<IBandTileClosedEvent> e)
    {
        // TODO: Handle the tile closing 
        LogEvent(String.Format("EventHandler_TileClosed: TileId={0} Timestamp={1}", e.TileEvent.TileId, e.TileEvent.Timestamp));

        // Disconnect the Band now that the user has closed the tile.
        DisconnectBand();
    }  
    private  void EventHandler_TileButtonPressed(object sender, BandTileEventArgs<IBandTileButtonPressedEvent> e)
    {
        // TODO: Handle the button push 
        LogEvent(String.Format("EventHandler_TileButtonPressed: TileId={0} PageId={1} ElementId={2}", e.TileEvent.TileId, e.TileEvent.PageId, e.TileEvent.ElementId));
        // We should have a Band connection from the tile open event, but in case the OS unloaded our background code
        // between that event and this button press event, we restore the connection here as needed.
        ConnectBand();
        var tileid = e.TileEvent.TileId;
        SendMessage(tileid);
        //await new MessageDialog("This is an background task"+tileid).ShowAsync();
    }
    private void ConnectBand()
    {
        if (this.bandClient == null)
        {
            // Note that we specify isBackground = true here to avoid conflicting with any foreground app connection to the Band
            Task<IBandInfo[]> getBands = BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync(isBackground: true);
            getBands.Wait();
            IBandInfo[] pairedBands = getBands.Result;

            if (pairedBands.Length == 0)
            {
                LogEvent("ERROR - No paired Band");
            }

            try
            {
                Task<IBandClient> connect = BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0]);
                connect.Wait();
                this.bandClient = connect.Result;
            }
            catch
            {
                LogEvent("ERROR - Unable to connect to Band");
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If currently connected to the Band, then disconnect.
    /// </summary>
    private void DisconnectBand()
    {
        if (bandClient != null)
        {
            bandClient.Dispose();
            bandClient = null;
        }
    }
    const string LogFileName = "EventLog.txt";

    /// <summary>
    /// Log event strings to a text file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="eventString">String describing the event</param>
    private void LogEvent(string eventString)
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("EventLog.txt", FileMode.Append))
        {
            string outputString = String.Format("{0}: {1}\r\n", DateTime.Now, eventString);
            byte[] outputASCII = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(outputString);
            stream.Write(outputASCII, 0, outputASCII.Length);
        }
    }
    private async void SendMessage(Guid tileGuid)
    {
        try
        {     // Send a message to the Band for one of our tiles, 
              // and show it as a dialog. 
            await bandClient.NotificationManager.SendMessageAsync(tileGuid, "Task", "This is an AppService Task", DateTimeOffset.Now, MessageFlags.ShowDialog);

        }
        catch (BandException ex)
        {

            // handle a Band connection exception
        }
    }
}
```

}

Please tell me how to resolve the above issue and tell me how to debug the appservice in VS 2015 but not a background task.

Regards,
Pradeep